# Compute pseudoinverse by hand

Tags: matlab

I follow the formula on wiki:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_inverse

to compute pseudoinverse but i can not receive the right result. for example:
I want to find `theta` of the equation: `Y=R*theta`, i write on matlab:

```
R = -[1/sqrt(2) 1 1/sqrt(2) 0;0 1/sqrt(2) 1 1/sqrt(2);-1/sqrt(2) 0 1/sqrt(2) 1];
% R is 3x4 matrix

Y = [0; -1/sqrt(2);-1]; %Y is 3x1 matrix

B1 = pinv(R);
theta1 = B1*Y;
result1 = R*theta1 - Y

B2 = R'*inv(R*R');
theta2 = B2*Y;
result2 = R*theta2 - Y
```

and this is the result:

```
   result1 =
   1.0e-15 *
   -0.1110
   -0.2220
   -0.2220
Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled.
Results may be inaccurate. RCOND =  1.904842e-17. 
> In pseudoinverse at 14 
result2 =
    0.1036
   -0.1768
   -0.3536
```

Cleary, theta2 is the wrong answer, but i don't know how and why. I read many book and they give me the same formula as wiki.
Can anybody help me to do pseudo inverse by hand ? thanks !

Comment: I think you mean "`theta1` is the wrong answer" as you have it written.

Comment: It's `theta2`. `theta1` right because `result1`~0, and `theta2` wrong because `result2` <>0

Comment: It's not `theta2`. You have no variable called `theta2`. What you call theta2 is named `theta1` in your script. I'm just trying to carify your question for others. I can't edit your question to change just one character -you need to do that.

Comment: yeah, I see it, thanks ^^

Answer (score 4):

The algebra tells you that a pseudo-inverse can be used to solve such equations, but the algebra isn't accounting for finite precision computation.

In fact computation of a pseudo-inverse using the matrix multiplication method is not suitable because it is numerically unstable.  Use the `\` operator for matrix division, as in

```
theta = R \ Y;
```

Algebraically, matrix division is the same as multiplication by pseudo-inverse.  But MATLAB's implementation is far more stable.

For more information, including stable methods, see

- [Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Construction) on Wikipedia

Comment: thanks for answer, but in my problem, `pinv()` show the right answer, and formula `B1 = R'*inv(R*R');` is wrong. I want to know how the `pinv` implement.
And I try `theta = R \ B;` matlab give a error 
`??? Error using ==> mldivide
Matrix dimensions must agree.`

Comment: @kerry_13: See the link I provided.  It's unclear why you hasn't already seen that, since it is linked several times from the page you linked in your answer.

Comment: Sorry about the typo.  You're using `B` for the pseudo-inverse, I'm accustomed to systems of equations described by `Ax = b` and then the solution is `x = A \ b;`

Comment: type `edit pinv` in the Matlab command window. You'll see that the function is based on the `svd` function ([singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)) -just as is indicated in the Wikipedia link from @BenVoigt.

Answer (score 1):

As Ben has already said, matrix inversion is numerically unstable. The function `inv` is not recommended unless you want to have the actual inversion of a matrix, see for example [this link](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/). The misuse of `inv` is the mistake a new student of numerical linear algebra most often makes.

In most linear algebra computations, you can circumvent `inv` by using a numerically-stable algorithm. For example, we have LU factorization for linear solvers, and QR or SVD method for ordinary least squares.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calculating B1 correctly. In your case

```
B1 = inv(R'*R)*R';
```

Because R is leading (traditionally it is the other way around). However, that doesn't solve your singularity problem.

pinv used SVD to calculate the pseudo-inverse, which you can read about [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Applications_of_the_SVD).

So basically it does in a more elegant fashion:

```
[U,S,V] = svd(R);
S(abs(S)<(sum(sum(S))*1e-8)) = 0; % removes near-singular values.
Stemp = 1./S;
Stemp(isinf(Stemp)) = 0; % This take the inverse of non-zero terms... I'm sure there is faster way
B1 = V * Stemp' * U';
```

And then you can continue on your way...